# iterate rows and print based on condition pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, row

i have a dataset that i read in with pd.read_excel

```
Block     Con     
  1       100      
  1       100      
  1       100      
  1       33      
  1       33       
  1       33
  2       100
  2       100
  2       100
  2       33
  2       33
  2       33
...
```

there are a total of 10 'block's, each 'block' has 2 types of 'con': 100 and 33.
how can i iterate through the 'Block' column so that for each 'block' it prints out the 2 types of 'con': 100 and 33

desire output:

```
      1      100
              33
      2       100
              33
```

my code:

```
for b in data.Block:
     for c in data.Con:
         print(c)
```

but it prints out all of the con for each row of block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use drop_duplicates:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
    Block  Con
0       1  100
1       1  100
2       1  100
3       1   33
4       1   33
5       1   33
6       2  100
7       2  100
8       2  100
9       2   33
10      2   33
11      2   33

In [12]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[12]:
   Block  Con
0      1  100
3      1   33
6      2  100
9      2   33
```

Comment: thank you, that makes perfect sense.  but my actual table is much more complicated than this, that why i was wondering how to iterate through the rows by some condition.  please see my edited post.

Comment: @Jessica you should ask this as another question rather than edit the old one to change it. That way if someone else googles for your question/answer they find this :)

Comment: please see my new post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573329/iterate-through-rows-on-condition-pandas-python

Answer (score 0):

I would use `groupby` in this way:

```
d = df.groupby(['Block','Con']).size()
```

which returns:

```
Block  Con
1      33     3
       100    3
2      33     3
       100    3
```

Comment: thank you, but my actual table is much more complicated than this, please see my edited post.

Comment: please see my new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573329/iterate-through-rows-on-condition-pandas-python